# Define operator using pipe symbol in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, symbols

I would like to know if this can be done:

```
data NumeroConBase = NumeroConBase { num :: Integer, base :: Integer}

(|) :: String -> Int -> NumeroConBase
```

Basically, I would like to write `344D|5` and work with that...

I'm getting an error on `"|"`...

Answer (score 13):

`|` is one of the very few symbol sequences which cannot be used as an operator name in Haskell. The [full list](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) is: `..`, `:`, `::`, `=`, `\`, `|`, `<-`, `->`, `@`, `~`, `=>` and the comment delimiters. All of these have special syntactical meaning. In your case, the lone pipe is used in guards and `data` declarations.

(Minutiae: the restrictions only apply if the sequences are used on their own; so something like `@@` or `-->` works fine. Also, operators starting with `:` can only be used as infix constructors in `data` declarations.)

Comment: Indeed, otherwise `x | True = 5::Int` could be a definition of `x :: Int` or of `(|) :: a -> Bool -> Int`, so an ambiguity arises.